# Print with XPS and Printer in the same time

Tags: printing, printf, xps

Can you print at the same time in two modes?
1- XPS
2- Printer (َAll models)

If the above item is not possibleو Could you write a program in C# to save a copy of it as a file in the form of an X before printing?

Please guide me in this regard

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @arasto, can you share with us more on what you have done to research this and also what you have attempted to do in your program? This will help users to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The [Win2PDF](https://www.win2pdf.com) printer can do this.  When you print to the Win2PDF printer, change the "Save As Type" to XPS, and check the "Print File" option:
[image: Win2PDF File Save]

If you want to save and print the file without displaying the File Save window, you can enable the Win2PDF "Auto-name" feature as described here:
https://www.win2pdf.com/doc/automatically-name-pdf.html